# parsing xml site using elementtree

Tags: python, xml, xbmc

```
import elementtree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib  

name = name.lower().replace(' ','%20')
id_search = 'http://services.tvrage.com/myfeeds/search.php?key=ag6txjP0RH4m0c8sZk2j&show='+name
tree = ET.parse(urllib.urlopen(id_search))
root = tree.getroot()
showid = root.find('showid')
url = 'http://services.tvrage.com/myfeeds/episode_list.php?key=ag6txjP0RH4m0c8sZk2j&sid='+str(showid)
```

For some reason the `showid` comes up as none. Any help on this would be great. I'm using this on xbmc addon to scrape the showid.

Here is the link http://services.tvrage.com/myfeeds/search.php?key=ag6txjP0RH4m0c8sZk2j&show=black%20sails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root-element of the xml-file is the `results`-element, only containing `show`-elements. You're trying to take subelement `show-id` from `results`, while `show-id`-elements are all subelements of `show`.

You could use `showid = root.find('show/show-id')`, but probably you want toe use a for-loop and the findall-function instead of the find-function.